# PHP script printing div

Tags: php, html, css

Is there a possible way to multiply code and print it out using PHP?
I am trying to make a script that checks users and draws a line depending on count.

CSS Code

```
#outer {                            // gray backround - always on.
    background-color: #401800;
    width: 150px;
    height: 6px;
}

.inner {               // used if there's less than 100 ppl online
    width: 1px;
    height: 6px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.bigger {             // used if 100+ people are online
    width: 10px;
    height: 6px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
}
.bigger.trys { // color for small px
    background-color: green;
}

.inner.vienas { //color for big px
    background-color: green;
}
```

PHP code ($rows = counted users):

```
if {$rows <= "0"
    echo"<span class="inner vienas"></span>"; //draws small 1px width bar
    }
elseif{$rows >= "10"
    echo"<span class="inner vienas"></span><span class="inner vienas"> </span>"; // count =10 or greater - draws x2 bars.
    }

elseif{$rows >= "100" // if users are 100 OR more counts new variable
    $padala = $rows/10 //variable is users/10
    echo 10*"<span class="bigger trys"></span>") //i want to print this out as 1px each 10 users
    }
else {
echo "Script error";
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but yes you have syntax error, read up: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Also loop basics: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax. Get a good book or find an online tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you have lot of syntax error.

First, if statement need a condition:

***Wrong:***

```
if {
   $rows <= "0"
   echo"<span class="inner vienas"></span>"; //draws small 1px width bar
}
```

***Correct*** (i don't know if `$row` have an integer or string, but if you use numbers, the correct is to storage an integer):

```
if ($rows <= 0) {
        echo '<span class="inner vienas"></span>';
      }
```

Second, `echo`:
You have an error with double quote marks when inserting HTML code, you don't have to cut the `echo`

***Wrong:***

```
echo"<span class="inner vienas"></span>";
```

***Correct (using simple quotes):***

```
echo '<span class="inner vienas"></span>';
```

Another error is that `echo*10`, you need to use a for loop.

```
for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) { 
   echo '<span class="bigger trys"></span>';
}
```

Btw, I don't understand what you want, but the correct maybe is this:

```
  if ($rows <= 0) {
    echo '<span class="inner vienas"></span>';
  } else if ($rows >= 10) {
    echo '<span class="inner vienas"></span><span class="inner vienas"> </span>'; 
  } else if ($rows >= 100) { 
    $padala = $rows / 10 
        for($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) { 
            echo '<span class="bigger trys"></span>';
        }
  } else {
      echo "Script error";
  }
```

Here you can read more about if statements and for:

[**PHP Manual - If Statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

[**PHP W3Schools - For loops**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your data, I'm not sure how I would go about doing what you want to accomplish.  However, Here is your above code with the syntax fixes. 
The conditions in the if statements should be wrapped in Parentheses, and the double quotes in the strings after the the echo functions should be escaped

```
if ($rows <= "0") {
    echo"<span class=\"inner vienas\"></span>"; //draws small 1px width bar
} elseif($rows >= "10") {
    echo"<span class=\"inner vienas\"></span><span class=\"inner vienas\"> </span>"; // count =10 or greater - draws x2 bars.
} elseif($rows >= "100") { // if users are 100 OR more counts new variable
    $padala = $rows/10 //variable is users/10
    echo 10*"<span class=\"bigger trys\"></span>") //i want to print this out as 1px each 10 users
} else {
    echo "Script error";
}
```